# Sending and receiving data over USB using serial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to send data from PC to Raspberry Pi Pico. PC code:

```
import serial
import time

# Define the serial port and baud rate (adjust as needed)
serial_port = 'COM12'  # Replace 'X' with the actual COM port number
baud_rate = 9600

try:
    # Open the serial port
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=1)
    print(f"Connected to {serial_port} at {baud_rate} baud")

    while True:
        # Data to send to the Raspberry Pi Pico
        data_to_send = "Hello, Raspberry Pi Pico!\n"

        # Send the data
        ser.write(data_to_send.encode())

        # Wait for a while before sending again (adjust as needed)
        time.sleep(2)

except serial.SerialException as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
finally:
    ser.close()
```

I get:

> Connected to COM12 at 9600 baud

So I expected it to work. Raspberry Pi Pico code:

```
import machine
from machine import Pin
import time
import sys


led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
# Create a UART object on UART0 (default Pico UART)
uart = machine.UART(0, baudrate=9600)

while True:
    try:
        data = uart.readline()
        if data:
            print(data.decode('utf-8'), end='')  # Print received data
            led.toggle()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    time.sleep(0.1)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed
```

For debugging I added a LED toggle in Raspberry Pi Pico code to know when I received data but the LED just stays on. I expected it to turn on and off every 2 seconds. Raspberry Pi Pico script is named main.py to make it auto-run.

Comment: You're making debugging complicated for yourself by using too many untested components all at once: (1) your PC program, (2) your Pico program, and (3) the serial connection. If all three have flaws, you can make one change somewhere but you will be unable to confirm if it fixes anything.  First replace your untested programs with proven terminal emulation programs, such as PuTTY, minicom, picocom, etc. to verify that your serial link is functional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read/write data over Raspberry Pi Pico USB cable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138267/read-write-data-over-raspberry-pi-pico-usb-cable)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same/similar question as [Read/write data over Raspberry Pi Pico USB cable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138267/read-write-data-over-raspberry-pi-pico-usb-cable)

By using `machine.UART` you utilise a raw UART connection, not the USB port. If you actually want to use UART, you would have to attach a UART-USB-converter like a CP2102 or similar to the corresponding pins on the Pico, see [RP2 MicroPython Docs](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/rp2/quickref.html#uart-serial-bus)